# Graph isomorphisms on 6 vertices with degree 3

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I want to find another graph that has 6 vertices and each has degree $3$ that is not isomorphic to these two graphs below. I know that these two graphs are isomorphic. They will all have the same degree sequence, So I kind of stuck how to find such graph. Any suggestions ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw two triangles and join them with a 1-factor.

Comment: What do you mean, join them with a 1-factor ?

Comment: 1-factor is a perfect matching. Choose a vertex from the first triangle and join it with a vertex from the second triangle. After that choose a second vertex from the first triangle and join it to another vertex from the second triangle, and so on. If you do not want to get vertex with degree 4 or 5, then you can do this uniquely up to isomorphisms.

Comment: Ok I got this, Now Why is this graph not isomorphic to the other two graphs ?

Comment: because this graph contains a triangle, while yours does not.

Comment: But what makes it not isomorphic still, Like what makes the triangle showing up in this graph not isomorphic ?

Comment: If you have a triangle in one graph, then an isomorphisms maps it to a triangle. (Because if $u-v-w-u$ is a triangle in the first, then $f(u)-f(v)-f(w)-f(u)$ will be a triangle in the second, where $f$ is the isomorphism.) So if you have two graphs, where one does contain a triangle, and the second does not, then these two graphs cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

A graph on $6$ vertices is regular of degree $3$ if and only if its complement is regular of degree $2.$

First find two nonisomorphic $2$-regular graphs on $6$ vertices (hint: one is connected, the other is not); their complements will be nonisomorphic $3$-regular graphs on $6$ vertices.

Answer (score 0):

This graph being $3-regular$ on $6$ vertices always contain exactly $9$ edges.

One possible graph is as follows:

-Join the vertices $1,2,3,4,5,6$ by making parallel edges between each pair $1$ & $2$, $3$ & $4$, and $5$ & $6$. This will exhaust $6$ of your edges. Now join each pair $2$ & $3$, $4$ & $5$, $6$ & $1$ by using $3$ more edges.
 -

As this graph is not simple hence cannot be isomorphic to any graph you have given.

Answer (score 0):

The Stefan Gyürki's answer and the author's one can solve one variant of this question. If we change the question to be **more specific**, we can find one nonisomorphic graph based on more conditions to use.

> Find the number of nonisomorphic **simple** graphs with
> six vertices in which each vertex has degree three.

This is shown in this [lecture](https://web.archive.org/web/20240112024455/http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/jozef/MA210/06sol.pdf) p2. Here I give some notes for this doc.

1. Since the lecture doesn't consider the case where the vertices are splitted into 3 pairs and each pair are connected with one endpoint has one loop, here it probably assumes the 3-regular graph is one simple graph, although it is [not always this case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1513147/1059606).
2. Since this is one **unlabelled** vertex problem, so we can assume

   > Let x be any vertex of such 3-regular graph and a, b, c be its three neighbors.
3. It is splitted into 2 cases (whether $y,z$ are adjacent or not), so it will consider all possible cases.

   1. "If y and z are not adjacent", based on the assumption of the specific question, loops are excluded. So *only* the bipartite is possible.
   2. "By symmetry" is due to the assumption of "**unlabelled** vertex problem".

---

we can also use the bof's answer to solve the above specific variant.

Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2490502/1059606), if we exclude all loops (then only 1-(i),2-(i,ii),3-(i) are left) and all parallel edges (then only 1-(i),2-(i) are left), then we has only 2 graphs. This is same as the above method.